# One subcategory to multiple category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-theming

I am struggling to add one product subcategory to multiple main categories and until now i have no found for this point.

I want to have the following:

Category 1

- Subcategory 1
- Subcategory 2

Category 2

- Subcategory 1
- Subcategory 2

Do you know how I can make this happen?

If not is there any other option to have this?
Idk, maybe to create new subcategory which redirect to the subcategory i want?

Category 1

- Subcategory 1

Category 2

- Subcategory 2-> when click to redirect to Subcategory 1

Many thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: the simpliest way is to create menu. On both Cat 1 and Cat 2 add same sub element subcat 1 rename subcat1 in Cat 2 to subcat 2 thats all. You cant add sub cat to multiple parent categories. What url will that sub cat have ? doesnt make any sense right ?